# How to change the timezone with moment.js without changing the time?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a datepicker which returns local time in the format `dddd, MMMM DO YYYY, h:mm:ss a` to a variable `localTime`. I have an option to change the timezone from a `<select>` which contains timezone names from `moment.tz.names()`. When timezone changes, I need to change the timezone of `localTime` to new timezone without changing the time.How can I do this with moment.js

```
let timeString = "Wednesday, January 10th 2018, 9:10:19 pm";
let localTime = moment(timeString, 'dddd, MMMM DO YYYY, h:mm:ss a').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ');
let localTimeInUtc = moment(timeString, 'dddd, MMMM DO YYYY, h:mm:ss a').utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ');
let newTimezone = "EST";
let newTime = moment(timeString, 'dddd, MMMM DO YYYY, h:mm:ss a').tz(newTimezone).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ');
let newTimeInUtc = moment(timeString, 'dddd, MMMM DO YYYY, h:mm:ss a').tz(newTimezone).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ');
console.log(localTime);
console.log(localTimeInUtc);
console.log(newTime);
console.log(newTimeInUtc);
```

Here time in UTC is same for `localTime` and `newTime`

Comment: Please post some code (current HTML/JS etc.)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/)

Maybe you are looking for `format2` in the following code.

`format1` - creates moment and sets the time-zone (will not update the offset).
`format2` - creates the moment with the given timezone.

```js
var date = moment().format("dddd, MMMM D YYYY, h:mm:ss a"), format = "dddd, MMMM D YYYY, h:mm:ss a", timezone = "America/New_York";
var format1 = moment(date,format).tz(timezone);
var format2 = moment.tz(date, format,timezone);
console.log(format1.format(format)+" -> "+format1.format());
console.log(format2.format(format)+" -> "+format2.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

See this [Github issue](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/57) once.

Comment: Please note that your code throws _Deprecation warning_ and there is no `DO` token use `D`,`DD` or `Do` for day of the month.

Comment: Updated @VincenzoC