# Fullcalendar adding events across timezones

Tags: php, jquery, datetime, timezone, fullcalendar

I am clearly missing something completely fundamental regarding creating events in FullCalendar so am seeing if perhaps anyone has a solution or any advice.

**Objective:** Have a calendar function that counselors can use to let clients know what their opening times are (times are not full day and can be as short as one hour).

The counselors and clients are not necessarily going to be in the same timezone so  the events must be created in a way to reflect the time appropriate to the individual time zones.

For example, a counselor (in New Zealand) creates an available event starting at:

```
Friday, 1 March 2019 at 7:00:00 a.m.
```

The client in New York should see that event as:

```
Thursday, 28 February 2019 at 1:00:00 p.m
```

This is something that I am struggling to achieve and am not sure if it is even possible with FullCalendar

The "timezone" option doesn't seem to make any difference when creating events (and yes, I perfectly accept that I might be doing something completely wrong).

In this [calendar](https://jsfiddle.net/Mhluzi/1t08qeLk/88/) fiddle I have the timezone set as follows:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    timezone: 'Pacific/Auckland'
    ....
});
```

When I select 7am on March 1, 2019 FullCalendar generates the start date as UTC:

```
Fri Mar 01 2019 07:00:00 GMT+0000
```

If I use moment.tz to format that start date as Pacific/Auckland:

```
console.log(moment.tz(startDate, 'Pacific/Auckland').format());
```

I get:

```
2019-03-01T20:00:00+13:00
```

Which is a correct conversion of the original start date but obviously of no use in this instance as it is not the date expected.

If I drag and drop an event to 7am March 1, 2019 (see same [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mhluzi/1t08qeLk/88/)) and then click on it to write out the event object to the console using:

```
eventClick: function(event, element) 
{
    console.log("event: ");
    console.log(event);
},
```

The following is displayed (shortened here for simplicity):

```
    "_fc3"
    _start 
    Fri Mar 01 2019 07:00:00 GMT+0000 {...}
    _a
    [2019, 2, 1, 4 more...]
    _ambigTime
    false
    _ambigZone
    true
   _d
   Fri Mar 01 2019 20:00:00 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time) {}
```

So **_start** is Fri Mar 01 2019 07:00:00 GMT+0000 - which (ignoring the offset for now) is the time that it should be (as in, it should be 7am)

and **_d** is  Fri Mar 01 2019 20:00:00 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time) .

But I clearly can't save the value of **_d** as that is obviously not the desired time in this instance.

Also, if I save that _start date as it is to a MySQL datetime field it gets stored as "2019-03-01 07:00:00", (the MySQL server is set to UTC) and if I import that into the calendar it displays as 7am on March 1 2019 and doesn't factor in the user timezone.

As always I have checked SO for possible answers but no answers seem to address this issue.

As I said, I hope that I am just missing something fundamental.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Updated fiddle

**EDIT** Added image and explanation

In the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mhluzi/1t08qeLk/88/) (described in this image):

[image: image of fiddle]

1. Drag this to 7am (for example)
2. Click the event to access the event object
3. this shows the time in 4. as UTC/GMT
4. this shows the time in 6. as UTC/GMT
5. this shows the time in 8. as New Zealand timezone (for me as I am in NZ)

So I guess what I am missing here is how to get the public start property

What I am looking for/expecting is a start time of:

```
Sat Mar 02 2019 07:00:00 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
```

which is a UTC time of :

```
Friday, 1 March 2019 at 6:00:00 p.m. UTC
```

So that UTC Friday time is what I would expect to save in the database.

**Note:** I am actually in New Zealand so the fiddle will be different for anyone outside of that time zone.

Comment: when you send the date you saved in MySQL back to fullCalendar you have to include the timezone offset which fullCalendar will have requested. It's documented in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone - see the "Timezone string (like "America/Chicago")" section, it says "Your server-side script is then expected to use the timezone parameter to calculate the timezone offset of the returned ISO8601 dates". In other words, fullCalendar will send the server the timezone of the user who is requesting the data, and you have to use that info to alter the response you send back.

Comment: I'm sorry that my question is not clear - this is not so much about displaying the data that is saved - rather how or what to save in the first place. 

Because as I see it the start date of the event object is in UTC and not the timezone of the browser. See the part of the question where I state: _start is Fri Mar 01 2019 07:00:00 ....GMT+0000

Comment: " the start date of the event object is in UTC and not the timezone of the browser"...that's a good thing. Like I just said, if you save it to the database in UTC then it's universal - it's the same for everyone. Then making it look right to each user is merely a matter of being told their timezone and adding the appropriate offset when you give them back the data. The principle is: store the data in a universal format (UTC is ideal for this) and then the only time you have to convert it to the local time is when you want to display it to a user in that timezone.

Comment: This gives you the ability to be able to save data from any user in any timezone and re-display it to any user in any other timezone, because at the centre of it you have a consistent non-localised storage format. So as long as when the user sends a request for data they include their desired timezone (and fullCalendar will do this for you, if you configure your event sources in the recommended way), and then can get your standardised data and convert it to the right format according to the request. It should be relatively straightforward to achieve.

Comment: BTW the discrepancy you're seeing in the console log (with and without timezone) is no doubt related to how fullCalendar stores the dates internally. You're looking at the internal properties of the event object there, which is not really the way fullCalendar wants you to interact with it. Instead, get the public `start` property of the event. It will be a momentJS object and may have timezone info attached to it there (although as the docs note, if you dragged it it can become ambiguously zoned - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/moment#ambiguously-zoned) which might be a complication

Comment: I think basically that when you send the data to the server to be stored, you either need to send it in UTC format, and then the server saves it as-is, or you send it in the local timezone and include an offset (or other way of knowing the timezone) so that the server then knows how to convert it to UTC for saving. In the example you gave where you dragged it to a certain time and it then showed you the time in UTC, a) I don't know exactly what you logged to get that output, but b) if you just send that to the server with the correct timezone info instead, then the server can convert to UTC

Comment: I have made an edit to the question - you mentioned "public start property"  -  I think that is what I am not getting...

Comment: And yes, I do completely agree - I definitely do want to save the dates as UTC.....

Comment: instead of logging the raw event object and looking at the internals, what does `event.start.format()` output? That's what I meant by looking at the public property. `start` is a momentJS object, so you should use moment's documented interface to interact with it.

Comment: P.S. I notice your moment is indeed ambiguously-zoned (`ambigZone` is `true`) so that's probably why it's not reporting what you expected. It has no timezone information.

Comment: Ah, right, so event.start.format returns: 2019-03-02T07:00:00

So I then need to convert that to UTC and then save that .....will give that a go...

Comment: With some credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48191207/5947043), here's a little demo script that will add timezone info back into your moment without actually mutating the time (which is what happens if you use the built-in methods like utcOffset()): http://jsfiddle.net/2hvdy653/ . Now you can send that string including the timezone offset to your server, and it then will be able to know to convert it to UTC in order to save it in the database.

Comment: Legend, thank you,will see how that goes...

Comment: Please understand that field that start with underscores (`_`) are *internal* and not meant to be used directly.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28132227/634824

Answer (score 1):

I've done similar project by storing all date times in UTC. This way it was easy to show time in any timezones.

I've achieved above as below:

- step 1: I created a dropdown to select the timezone.
- step 2: initialise fullcalendar on the page
- step 3: with moment.js, guess users timezone.
- step 4: convert the calendar timezone to UTC
- step 5: Ajax to save the dropped event with UTC time
- step 6: when rendering the event, show the default timezone from the dropdown

else show user selected timezone.

```
  let calendar = $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        defaultView: "agendaWeek",
        header: {
            left: "prev,next today",
            center: "title",
            right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
        },
        now: moment().format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
        height: "auto",
        slotDuration: "00:30:00",
        defaultTimedEventDuration: "00:30:00",
        timezone: "local",
        weekends: false,
        dragRevertDuration: 0,
        allDaySlot: false,
        slotEventOverlap: false,
        editable: true,
        eventStartEditable: true,
        eventDurationEditable: true,
        droppable: true,
        eventSources: [
            fcSources.loadEvents,
            fcSources.loadEwsEvents
        ],
        businessHours: [ // highlight working hours
            {
                dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // weekdays
                start: '08:00',
                end: '18:00'
            }
        ],
        drop: function (date) {
            //Call when you drop slot for the first time
            let defaultDuration = moment.duration($("#calendar").fullCalendar("option", "defaultTimedEventDuration"));
            $("input[name='EVENTS[ID]']").val(null);
            $("input[name='EVENTS[TITLE]']").val($(this).data().event.title);
            $("input[name='EVENTS[EVENT_START]']").val($(this).convertTimeToUTC(date));
            $("input[name='EVENTS[EVENT_END]']").val($(this).convertTimeToUTC(date.clone().add(defaultDuration)));
            $(this).addCalendarEvent();
        },
        eventOverlap: function (stillEvent, movingEvent) {
            return stillEvent.allDay && movingEvent.allDay;
        },
        eventDrop: function (event) {
                $("input[name='EVENTS[ID]']").val(event.id);
                $("input[name='EVENTS[TITLE]']").val(event.title);
                $("input[name='EVENTS[EVENT_START]']").val($(this).convertTimeToUTC(event.start));
                $("input[name='EVENTS[EVENT_END]']").val($(this).convertTimeToUTC(event.end));
            //if the call is confirmed or complete then do not move it
                if ($.trim(event.status) !== "COMPLETE" && $.trim(event.status) !== "CONFIRMED") {
                    $(this).updateCalendarEvent();
                }
        }
    });
```

//then select dropdown

```
  //self initialising function for timezones dropdown
    (function(window, document, $, undefined){
        const _t = (s) => {
            if (i18n !== void 0 && i18n[s]) {
                return i18n[s];
            }
            return s;
        };
        const timezones = [
            "Etc/GMT+12",
            "Pacific/Midway",
            "Pacific/Honolulu",
            "America/Juneau",
            "America/Dawson",
            "America/Boise",
            "America/Chihuahua",
            "America/Phoenix",
            "America/Chicago",
            "America/Regina",
            "America/Mexico_City",
            "America/Belize",
            "America/Detroit",
            "America/Indiana/Indianapolis",
            "America/Bogota",
            "America/Glace_Bay",
            "America/Caracas",
            "America/Santiago",
            "America/St_Johns",
            "America/Sao_Paulo",
            "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires",
            "America/Godthab",
            "Etc/GMT+2",
            "Atlantic/Azores",
            "Atlantic/Cape_Verde",
            "GMT",
            "Africa/Casablanca",
            "Atlantic/Canary",
            "Europe/Belgrade",
            "Europe/Sarajevo",
            "Europe/Brussels",
            "Europe/Amsterdam",
            "Africa/Algiers",
            "Europe/Bucharest",
            "Africa/Cairo",
            "Europe/London",
            "Europe/Helsinki",
            "Europe/Athens",
            "Asia/Jerusalem",
            "Africa/Harare",
            "Europe/Moscow",
            "Asia/Kuwait",
            "Africa/Nairobi",
            "Asia/Baghdad",
            "Asia/Tehran",
            "Asia/Dubai",
            "Asia/Baku",
            "Asia/Kabul",
            "Asia/Yekaterinburg",
            "Asia/Karachi",
            "Asia/Kolkata",
            "Asia/Kathmandu",
            "Asia/Dhaka",
            "Asia/Colombo",
            "Asia/Almaty",
            "Asia/Rangoon",
            "Asia/Bangkok",
            "Asia/Krasnoyarsk",
            "Asia/Shanghai",
            "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur",
            "Asia/Taipei",
            "Australia/Perth",
            "Asia/Irkutsk",
            "Asia/Seoul",
            "Asia/Tokyo",
            "Asia/Yakutsk",
            "Australia/Darwin",
            "Australia/Adelaide",
            "Australia/Sydney",
            "Australia/Brisbane",
            "Australia/Hobart",
            "Asia/Vladivostok",
            "Pacific/Guam",
            "Asia/Magadan",
            "Pacific/Fiji",
            "Pacific/Auckland",
            "Pacific/Tongatapu"
        ];
        const i18n = {
            "Etc/GMT+12": "International Date Line West",
            "Pacific/Midway": "Midway Island, Samoa",
            "Pacific/Honolulu": "Hawaii",
            "America/Juneau": "Alaska",
            "America/Dawson": "Pacific Time (US and Canada); Tijuana",
            "America/Boise": "Mountain Time (US and Canada)",
            "America/Chihuahua": "Chihuahua, La Paz, Mazatlan",
            "America/Phoenix": "Arizona",
            "America/Chicago": "Central Time (US and Canada)",
            "America/Regina": "Saskatchewan",
            "America/Mexico_City": "Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey",
            "America/Belize": "Central America",
            "America/Detroit": "Eastern Time (US and Canada)",
            "America/Indiana/Indianapolis": "Indiana (East)",
            "America/Bogota": "Bogota, Lima, Quito",
            "America/Glace_Bay": "Atlantic Time (Canada)",
            "America/Caracas": "Caracas, La Paz",
            "America/Santiago": "Santiago",
            "America/St_Johns": "Newfoundland and Labrador",
            "America/Sao_Paulo": "Brasilia",
            "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires": "Buenos Aires, Georgetown",
            "America/Godthab": "Greenland",
            "Etc/GMT+2": "Mid-Atlantic",
            "Atlantic/Azores": "Azores",
            "Atlantic/Cape_Verde": "Cape Verde Islands",
            "Europe/London": "Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London",
            "Africa/Casablanca": "Casablanca, Monrovia",
            "Atlantic/Canary": "Canary Islands",
            "Europe/Belgrade": "Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague",
            "Europe/Sarajevo": "Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb",
            "Europe/Brussels": "Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris",
            "Europe/Amsterdam": "Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna",
            "Africa/Algiers": "West Central Africa",
            "Europe/Bucharest": "Bucharest",
            "Africa/Cairo": "Cairo",
            "Europe/Helsinki": "Helsinki, Kiev, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius",
            "Europe/Athens": "Athens, Istanbul, Minsk",
            "Asia/Jerusalem": "Jerusalem",
            "Africa/Harare": "Harare, Pretoria",
            "Europe/Moscow": "Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd",
            "Asia/Kuwait": "Kuwait, Riyadh",
            "Africa/Nairobi": "Nairobi",
            "Asia/Baghdad": "Baghdad",
            "Asia/Tehran": "Tehran",
            "Asia/Dubai": "Abu Dhabi, Muscat",
            "Asia/Baku": "Baku, Tbilisi, Yerevan",
            "Asia/Kabul": "Kabul",
            "Asia/Yekaterinburg": "Ekaterinburg",
            "Asia/Karachi": "Islamabad, Karachi, Tashkent",
            "Asia/Kolkata": "Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi",
            "Asia/Kathmandu": "Kathmandu",
            "Asia/Dhaka": "Astana, Dhaka",
            "Asia/Colombo": "Sri Jayawardenepura",
            "Asia/Almaty": "Almaty, Novosibirsk",
            "Asia/Rangoon": "Yangon Rangoon",
            "Asia/Bangkok": "Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta",
            "Asia/Krasnoyarsk": "Krasnoyarsk",
            "Asia/Shanghai": "Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong SAR, Urumqi",
            "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur": "Kuala Lumpur, Singapore",
            "Asia/Taipei": "Taipei",
            "Australia/Perth": "Perth",
            "Asia/Irkutsk": "Irkutsk, Ulaanbaatar",
            "Asia/Seoul": "Seoul",
            "Asia/Tokyo": "Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo",
            "Asia/Yakutsk": "Yakutsk",
            "Australia/Darwin": "Darwin",
            "Australia/Adelaide": "Adelaide",
            "Australia/Sydney": "Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney",
            "Australia/Brisbane": "Brisbane",
            "Australia/Hobart": "Hobart",
            "Asia/Vladivostok": "Vladivostok",
            "Pacific/Guam": "Guam, Port Moresby",
            "Asia/Magadan": "Magadan, Solomon Islands, New Caledonia",
            "Pacific/Fiji": "Fiji Islands, Kamchatka, Marshall Islands",
            "Pacific/Auckland": "Auckland, Wellington",
            "Pacific/Tongatapu": "Nuku'alofa"
        };
        //get current time
        const dateTimeUtc = moment().utc();
        document.querySelector(".js-TimeUtc").innerHTML = dateTimeUtc.format("ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        const dateTimeLocal = moment().utc(moment.tz.guess());
        document.querySelector(".js-TimeLocal").innerHTML = dateTimeLocal.format("ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        const selectorOptions = moment.tz.names()
            .filter(tz => {
                return timezones.includes(tz)
            })
            .reduce((memo, tz) => {
                memo.push({
                    name: tz,
                    offset: moment.tz(tz).utcOffset()
                });

                return memo;
            }, [])
            .sort((a, b) => {
                return a.offset - b.offset
            })
            .reduce((memo, tz) => {
                const timezone = tz.offset ? moment.tz(tz.name).format('Z') : '';
                return memo.concat(`<option value="${tz.name}">${_t(tz.name)}</option>`);
            }, "");

        document.querySelector(".js-Selector").innerHTML = selectorOptions;

        $(".js-Selector").on("change", e => {
            const timestamp = dateTimeUtc.unix();
            const offset = moment.tz(e.target.value).utcOffset() * 60;
            const dateTimeSelected = moment.unix(timestamp + offset).utc();
            document.querySelector(".js-TimeSelected").innerHTML = dateTimeSelected.format("ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss");
            timeZone = $(".js-Selector").val();
            if(timeZone !=  moment.tz.guess()) {
                let timezoneWarningMessage = '<div class="alert alert-warning timezone-warning" role="alert" class="btn btn-indigo btn-sm ml-0 waves-effect waves-light bg-warning timezone-warning">' +
                    'Your timezone has been changed to <b>' + timeZone + '</b></div>';

                if($(".timezone-warning").length > 0) {
                    $(".timezone-warning").replaceWith(timezoneWarningMessage);
                } else {
                    $(".fc-view-container").prepend(timezoneWarningMessage);
                }
            } else {
                $(".timezone-warning").replaceWith('');
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'timezone', $(".js-Selector").val() || false);
        });

        document.querySelector(".js-Selector").value = "Europe/London";
        const event = new Event("change");
        document.querySelector(".js-Selector").dispatchEvent(event);
        $(".js-Selector").chosen();
    })(window, document, jQuery);
```

//now pass the selected timezone to eventsource

```
     let loadEvents: {
                url: "", //your url,
                type: "GET",
                cache: true,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    //based on the dropdown changetimezone of each event 

                    let updatedTime = [];
                    $.each(data.events, function( k, v ) {
                        v.start = moment.tz(v.start, timeZone);
                        v.end = moment.tz(v.end, timeZone);
                        updatedTime[k] = v ;
                    });
                    return updatedTime;
                }
            }

 //function to convert fullcalendar time to utc
    $.fn.convertTimeToUTC = function (convertTime) {
       if($(this).isObject(convertTime)) {
            return moment.tz(convertTime.format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"), moment.tz.guess()).utc().format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        }
    };
    // Returns if a value is an object
    $.fn.isObject =  function(value) {
        return value && typeof value === 'object';
    };
```